# How can a single CAN transreceiver be connected to two types of connectors?

Tags: can

I would like to connect a CAN transreceiver to the db9 connector and at the same time CAN line has to go another circuit. Is it possible to use only single transreceiver and have both access from connector and other circuit's connector?

Comment: Are you talking about daisy chaining using different connectors? Do a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to connect two or more CAN controllers/microcontrollers to the Tx/Rx lines of the transceiver while at the same time communicating with the rest of the bus, then no, that isn't possible.

Each controller/MCU needs its own CAN transceiver. You can then connect the CANH + CANL lines together on the PCB, as well as route them to the connector.

Also give some thought regarding how to connect this to the bus, will termination be needed on your board etc.